# Matplotlib FuncAnimation not working in windowed application using PyQT5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have a windowed application that, when a button is pressed, is supposed to trigger an animation of a 3d scatter plot using matplotlib. Here's my code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QListWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import platform
import sys
import six
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3

i = 1

def main():
    global device_app, device_listbox, device_win_conf_button, device_win
    device_app = QApplication(sys.argv)     # Initialize QApp
    device_win = QWidget()


    device_win_layout = QVBoxLayout()    # Layout

    device_win_conf_button = QPushButton("Proceed")

    device_app.aboutToQuit.connect(quit)

    device_win_conf_button.clicked.connect(plotAnimator)

    device_win_layout.addWidget(device_win_conf_button)
    device_win.setLayout(device_win_layout) # Assign layout to window and resize
    device_win.resize(500, 500)

    device_win.show()
    device_app.exec_()  # Enter loop

def plotAnimator():
    global sc_plot, x, y, z
    fig = plt.figure()  # Create matplotlib fig

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')  # Add plot
    ax.set_title("Example")
    ax.set_xlim3d(-10, 10) # Set bounds
    ax.set_ylim3d(-10, 10)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-10, 10)

    x = [0]
    y = [0]
    z = [0]
    sc_plot = ax.scatter(x,y,z) # Start at 0, 0, 0
    print(2)
    animation = FuncAnimation(fig, updatePlot, frames=2, interval=100)

    plt.show()

def updatePlot(frame):
    global i

    x.append(i)
    y.append(i)
    z.append(i)
    sc_plot._offsets3d = (x, y, z)
    i += 1

main()
```

So when I run this and click the button, the scatter plot shows up with the single point I've initialized it with at (0, 0, 0). I can interact with the plot, rotating it around and zooming in and out, yet there's no animation. Further, the following is printed to the console when I click the "Proceed" button:
`QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`.

I've researched this error and from what I understand it comes from trying to execute a `QApplication` that's already being executed. I don't see that happening in my code. The only thing I can think of is that maybe matplotlib uses PyQT to create its windows? Even if that was the case, though, I'm having trouble thinking about how I would fix it.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried witj PyQt4 ?

Comment: you might first uninstall PyQt5

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti Please don't advice people to uninstall PyQt5 if they run into such problems.

Comment: Make `animation` global as well to get the animation running (define `animation=None` at the start or similar). Use `fig.show()` instead of `plt.show()` when you already have an event loop running.

Comment: Ernest, you are an absolute wizard. You've been a huge help as I stumble through the nitty gritty details of matplotlib. Thanks a ton